# Couchbase connection pool in Java

Tags: java, connection-pooling, couchbase

Hello to you good people,

I work on a medium-concurrency web application and I need to record requests from the site users in a Couchbase database in real time. I expect reasonably high level of requests in the near future (several per minute in peak times). I know it doesn't sound like much at the moment, but I want to make it totally future proof.

So, I've been searching for an implementation of connection pool for Couchbase in Java. Basically, I want to create a connection pool to specify number of connections in the pool, etc.

Here is something I've been looking for in C#: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.0/configuring-the-client.html

But I could dig nothing up in Java. This article: https://dzone.com/articles/couchbase-java-sdk-internals explicitly states that "Note that there is absolutely no connection pooling needed inside the client, because we manage all sockets proactively..."

So, could anyone confirm whether we indeed do not need to manage connections as a pool (but just have one connection that handles all the requests, and thanks God it can do so asynchronously and uses internal caching for that) or if there is an implementation of Connection pool in Java for Couchbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a lot of [settings related to throughput and performance](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/java/client-settings.html#story-h2-6) when creating the connection, including how many concurrent TCP connections the client opens. So you absolutely should not implement any sort of external connection pooling on top of what the Java SDK already offers.

More importantly, you don't need to configure anything at all in your case. Just open the connection with the default settings and you'll easily send several thousand requests per second from a single client, if you use asynchronous operations. That's at least three orders of magnitude more than the several requests per minute you require.